# String Comparison: what does &gt mean

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I've got his line of code:

```
 if([searchText length] &gt; 0)
```

and I have no idea what it is doing and why it is giving me an error. I am following a tutorial about implementing a UISearchBar.

Comment: html-escaped greater-than symbol. Just change it to `>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML if you write `&gt;` the browser will show `>`.

This is good for preventing users from inserting their own HTML in something like a chat room. Or displaying HTML tags, without them actually be interpreted as HTML tags by the browser.

Wherever you copied your code may have mistakenly outputted `&amp;gt;`. `&amp;` is the HTML representation of `&`. So the HTML representation of "greater than" (`&gt;`) was not interpreted.

So in basic terms, it was a mistake on that site, and `&gt;` should actually be `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the line as:

```
if([searchText length] > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`&gt;` is the HTML escape sequence for `>`. Sometimes characters are converted to their escaped format to make sure text doesn't appear as HTML, usually they'll show up as the actual characters, but sometimes they don't.

This means that there's probably a few other escaped characters in the code, [here](http://www.htmlescape.net/escape_common.html) is a list of commonly escaped characters and what they are escaped to.